# No se puede convertir String a Double

Tags: java, jtable, cast

Tengo un `JTable` en donde cargo los datos que tengo en mi BD, con base a esos registros hago una operación sencilla, los datos que ingreso y con los que hago la operación los declaré como `Double`, en el momento de guardar los nuevos datos sin realizar la operación me sale el siguiente error, de igual manera si hago la operación tampoco me registra y sale el mismo error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

```
private void registrarInventarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

    try {

        int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
        System.out.println(rows);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


            String query = ("INSERT INTO ajuste_inventario_tmp(N_Ajuste,Categoria,ID,Referencia,Producto,UM,P_Compra,P_Venta,Teorico,Fisico,Diferencia,Nuevo_Inv) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            PreparedStatement sentencia = conexion.prepareStatement(query);
        for(int row = 0; row<rows ; row++)
        {
            variables.N_Ajuste = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
            variables.Categoria = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
            variables.ID = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
            variables.Referencia = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);
            variables.Producto = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 4);
            variables.UM = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 5);
            variables.P_Compra = (Double) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6);
            variables.P_Venta = (Double) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 7);
            variables.Teorico = (Double) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 8);
            variables.Fisico = (Double) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 9);
            variables.Diferencia  = (Double) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 10);
            String Nuevo_Inv = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 11);


            sentencia.setString(1, variables.N_Ajuste);           
            sentencia.setString(2, variables.Categoria);
            sentencia.setString(3, variables.ID);
            sentencia.setString(4, variables.Referencia);
            sentencia.setString(5, variables.Producto);
            sentencia.setString(6, variables.UM);
            sentencia.setDouble(7, variables.P_Compra);
            sentencia.setDouble(8, variables.P_Venta);
            sentencia.setDouble(9, variables.Teorico);
            sentencia.setDouble(10, variables.Fisico);
            sentencia.setDouble(11, variables.Diferencia);
            sentencia.setString(12, Nuevo_Inv);

            sentencia.executeUpdate();
        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inventario registrado");
    } catch (HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de conexión" + "\n" + e);
    }   
}
```

Se puede observar que traigo las variables de otra clase, estas ya están declaradas respectivamente.

Acá hago la operación:

```
        double Fisico = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tm.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),9)));
        double Teorico = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(tm.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(),8)));

        if (Fisico == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hubo cambios en la columna Fisico.");
        }else{
            double Diferencia = (Teorico - Fisico);
            if (Diferencia < 0) {
                Diferencia = (Diferencia * (-1));
            }
            tm.setValueAt(Diferencia, jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 10);
            jTable1.clearSelection();

        }
```

Comment: Lo que tienes es un string y no se puede pasar a double con un casteo, tienes que parsearlo y para ello tienes que poner Double.ParseDouble(string a convertir). No se si exactamente se escribe así pero es lo que teines que hacer

Comment: Por ejemplo: variables.P_Compra = Double.parseDouble((String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 6));?  @PabloSimonDiEstefano

Comment: Uff, es así amigo. ¡GRACIAS!

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano te invito a q re escribas tu comentario como respuesta para que asi el autor de la preguna pueda finalizar la misma. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes es un string y no se puede pasar a double con un casteo, tienes que parsearlo y para ello tienes que poner Double.ParseDouble(string a convertir). No se si exactamente se escribe así pero es lo que tienes que hacer.